# Blender 3.0 loop select

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

Why doesn't loop select work in this case?
In the status bar it says left click to loop select, I left click but it only selects one edge. When I select all 8 edges and do bridge edge loops it does the operation correctly so I'm guessing those are valid edge loops.

[image: Bug 100% confirmed]

Comment: hello, it's hard to see what you're doing

Comment: Look at the status bar, it says left click loop select, I left click but it only selects one edge.

Comment: Have you tried loop-selecting the same edge twice?

Comment: Yes it works then but I can't add another loop selection to it like I can with normal geometry (like an intact UV sphere). I'm more interested in why this happens, obviously I dealt with this by manually selecting every edge.